# how to add captcha in asp.net login form that work with ASp:Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am using `asp:login` object for login and also using **Membership security**.
I am really confuse about this because it is not working for me when I want to show message about incorrect login and incorrect captcha.
Please tell me an easy solutions that I can set message for each error.

Thank you

Comment: Here is an article which can help you : http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060706-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Sac , but I have captcha currently, My problem is when i am using this kind of login, I can show captcha error but showing loggin error message is not possible ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CatchpaRegistrationpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Employee_CatchpaRegistrationpage" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <div>

                <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

                <table style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 20px; position: relative; top: 50px;"
                    align="center">

                    <tr>

                        <td>EmailID :

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailID" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>Password :

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>Confirm Password :

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>Enter Below Code :

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td></td>

                        <td valign="middle">

                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">

                                <ContentTemplate>

                                    <table>

                                        <tr>

                                            <td style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">

                                                <asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" runat="server" />

                                            </td>

                                            <td valign="middle">

                                                <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />

                                            </td>

                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                </ContentTemplate>

                            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2" align="center">

                            <asp:Button ID="btnRegiser" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;


public partial class Employee_CatchpaRegistrationpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillCapctha();
        }
    }
    void FillCapctha()
    {
        try
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            string combination = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            StringBuilder captcha = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                captcha.Append(combination[random.Next(combination.Length)]);
                Session["captcha"] = captcha.ToString();
                imgCaptcha.ImageUrl = "CatchpaRegistrationpage.aspx?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillCapctha();
    }
    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["captcha"].ToString() != txtCaptcha.Text)
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid Captcha Code");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Valid Captcha Code");
        }
        FillCapctha();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. While your code may solve the question, please add some clarification to what the code does.